# ReliableDictionary <key, List>

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Is there any nice way to do a IReliableDictionary<key,List> ? I would imagine that the list would not be atomic and run into concurrency issues. Is there any nice way to do this ? I could imagine it would be useful for building indexes as well. eg  IReliableDictionary<index,List<Guid>>.

Comment: Do you mean [ConcurrentDictionary<TK,TV>?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not just concurrency issues, but data corruption and poor replication performance as well if you're not careful. Read through this guide for a detailed explanation: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-work-with-reliable-collections/

tl;dr:

- Every time you commit a transaction, the entire list is replicated and saved. If the list grows indefinitely, then so does replication time and cost.
- Your list better be immutable. If you make local changes directly to the list reference inside a transaction, and the transaction aborts (exception or something), your local changes will **not** be rolled back. If some other part of your code has a reference to the list and makes changes to the list outside of a transaction, those changes won't replicated and saved.

Comment: So how do you create a table / list like structure. eg IReliableList with sequential read type mechanics

Comment: WIll ask as another question